# Manipulating Output from cURL

Tags: linux, shell-script, curl

i want a way to extract 2 instances of digits following 2 different strings out of a long line of text produced from cURL http://website.com/.

So in this example output i want to grab both 23 and 144 and save them as different variables.

"AAABBBCCC" "Green":23',"AAABBBCCCCDDD" "Blue":144,"AAABBCCCDDDEEE" "Yellow":2,"

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract all the numbers with grep and read the first two:

```
{ read first; read second; } < <(curl "$url" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
```

Comment: The output can vary, so is it possible to look for a specific string such as "Green": and pull the following digits only?

Comment: Please edit your question and put **all** your requirements there.

Answer (score 1):

```
output=$(curl http://website.com/)
foo=${output#*:}
var1=${foo%%,*}
var2=${foo#*:}
var2=${var2%%,*}
```

Your answers are in `var1` and `var2`.  I'm guessing the `'` after the 23 was probably a typo.

Comment: Ah yes the ' was a typo.

Comment: I have changed my solution in response.